# How to typehint mixins if the target class for the mixin inherits from a metaclass?

Tags: python, mixins, type-hinting, metaclass

Consider the following class and mixin:

```py
class Target(ClassThatUsesAMetaclass):

    def foo(self):
        pass

class Mixin:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()  # type error: type checker doesn't know Mixin will have
                    # access to foo once in use.

class Combined(Mixin, Target):

    def __init__(self):
        Target.__init__(self)
        Mixin.__init__(self)
```

I'm trying to avoid the type checker error in the above scenario. One option is this:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class Fooable(Protocol):
    def foo(self): ...

class Mixin(Fooable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()
```

Would've worked great, except that `Target` inherits from a class that uses a metaclass, so `Combined` can't inherit from both `Target` and `Mixin`.
So now I'm trying an alternative, annotating `self` in `Mixin`:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .this import Mixin, Target
    Mixin_T = type('Mixin_T', (Mixin, Target), {})


class Mixin:

    def __init__(self: Mixin_T):
        self.foo()  # No longer an error

class Combined(Mixin, Target):

    def __init__(self):
        Target.__init__(self)
        Mixin.__init__(self)  # Now this is an error: "Type[Mixin]" is not
                              # assignable to parameter "self"
                              # "Mixin" is incompatible with "Mixin_T"
```

So how am I supposed to win this aside from using `# type: ignore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple solution:

```py
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .this import Target
    Mixin_T = Target
else:
    Mixin_T = object

class Mixin(Mixin_T):
    ...
```

Now all of `Target`'s methods are recognized within `Mixin` by the type checker, and there's no need to override the type of `self` into something imcompatible with `Mixin`. This might be a little awkward if the mixin is destined to all kinds of `Target` classes, but for my uses this is perfectly acceptable, since my case is a group of mixins extending a very specific target class.

Answer (score 1):

Other than that, there is to little code and some msconceptions above that make this question not answrable at all, apart from providing some clarifications.

To start, are you sure you are "inheriting from a metaclass"?? It does not make sense to inherit a metaclass unless to create *another* metaclass. Your snippets show you inhriting froma supposed metaclass (with no code given), to create  `Target` and them attempting to use `Target` as a parent to a normal class (a non-meta class). That makes no sense.

You might just have confused the terms and the hidden `InheritFromMetaclass` class actually just uses the metaclass, and do not "inherit" from it. Then your problem does not have to do with metaclasses at all.

So, the real visible problem in the snippet is that the static checkr does not "see" a `self.foo` method in the Mixin class - and guess what? There is *no* `self.foo` method in `Mixin` - the checker is just throwing a cold truth in your face: while Python does *allow* one to reference methods and attributes that are not available in a class, knowing that it will be used along other classes that do have those attributes, that is no good design and error prone. The kind of bad design static type checking exists to weed-off.

So, what you need is to have a base of `Mixin` that is an abstract class and have `Foo` as an abstract method. (Or have `Mixin` itself be that abstract class).

If - due to usage of other metaclass you can't have Mixin inheit from `abc.ABC` due to metaclass conflict, you have to either: create a combined metaclass from the metaclass acutually used by `InheritsFromMetaclass` with `ABCMeta` , nd use that as the metaclass for `Mixin`  - or just create a stub `foo` method in `Mixin` as is (which could raise a `NotImplementedError` - thus having the same behavior of an abstract method, but without really having to inherit from it.

The important part to have in and is that an methods and attributes you access in code inside a class body have to exist in that class, without depending on attributes that will exist in a subclass of it.

If that does not solve your problem, you need to provide more data - including a reproducible complete example involving your actual metaclass. (and it mgt be solved just by combining the metaclasses as mentioned above)

Comment: You are correct, I meant inherits from a class that uses a metaclass, I'll update the question. Regarding the mixin implementation itself, I agree that it's ugly, but I'm not familiar with another way to design a mixin in Python given how it tries to 'keep things simple' and not provide advanced OOP facilities. I'm familiar with the use of metaclasses to define an 'interface', but this forces me to mess with someone else's class hierarchy, which is not something I should not care about. I should be able to tell the static type checker that "this supports that", and only have to do that once.

Comment: ...also, you can have typing.Protocol as a base for a concrete class, see the PEP. It's how you denote protocol compatibility explicitly.

Comment: Yes - sorry for the protocol part, while writting the answer I even tested it and saw it working, but then I forgot to remove the first paragraph. I am glad it worked now.